# How to design list of images showing 5 images in datagrid and showing + symbol for remaining images like facebook newsfeed

Tags: javascript, html, ios, facebook, react-native

How to design list of images showing 5 images in datagrid and showing + symbol for remaining images like facebook newsfeed.

[image]

in ios or android or html or react-native,
any library is there for this kind of view.

Comment: what have you tried? post all of your code in the [![javascripts/html/css snippet code editor][1]][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NXyuj.png

Comment: i tried to use freewall jquery editor it is aligning the images but not as expected as above image http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/example/image-layout.html

Comment: post your code here for us to see what you have and/or a link to a working website you have uploaded with this problem